# C#.net - MS Access - insert into statement giving error "Syntax Error",

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

```
insertBankMas = ""; 
insertBankMas = "INSERT INTO IntNotes (Room,Size) VALUES('" + txtRoom.Text + "','" + txtSize.Text + "')";    
PbdataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(insertBankMas, PbSQLConnection);
openconnection();

insertcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Room is Added");
```

Please correct me...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You should tell us the details of your syntax error. And your code is wide open for  [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/)!

Comment: And is your `Size` column of numeric or string type? If it's numeric, remove the `'` from the `...'" + txtSize.Text + "'...`.

Answer (score 2):

`SIZE` is a [reserved keyword](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321266) for Microsoft OleDb provider. You need to use it with square brackets like `[SIZE]`. As a best practice, change it to *non*-reserved word. And since your sql is an `INSERT` query, you don't need `OleDbDataAdapter`. This structure will use when you get data from your database. Just use [`ExecuteNonQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.executenonquery) to execute your insert query.

#### Bur more important

You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `OleDbConnection` and `OleDbCommand` automatically instead of calling `Close` or `Dispose` methods manually.

```
using(var connection = new OleDbConnection(conString))
using(var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO IntNotes (Room, [Size]) VALUES(?, ?)";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtRoom.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtSize.Text;
    // I assume your column types mapped with VarWChar
   
    connection.Open();
    int effectedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if(effectedRows > 0)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Room is Added");
    }   
}
```

By the way, I *strongly* suspect your `Size` column should(?) be some numeric value based on it's name. You *might* wanna change it's column type instead.

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably happening because the data that you enter in textboxes contains special characters that need to be escaped. Even if the data does not need to be escaped you must not build sql commands using string concatenation because that can cause sql injection attacks. Instead you should use parameterized statements and pass the user data as parameters.

See this article for more details: 
[SQL Injection Attacks and Some Tips on How to Prevent Them](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9378/SQL-Injection-Attacks-and-Some-Tips-on-How-to-Prev)

Answer (score 0):

My Sincere thanks to everyone, reminded me SIZE is a keyword.  Its WORKING, When I changed the SIZE field name to ROOMSIZE

Thanks
Ram

Comment: It's probably better to delete this post and just accept Soner's answer by clicking on the check mark next to it.